# Random Variables and Floor Function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a r.v. and $n\in \mathbb{N}$. We look at
$$
X_{(n)}:=\frac{\left \lfloor{nX}\right \rfloor}{n}
$$
How do I show that $X_{(n)}$ is a discrete r.v.?

Comment: Hint: $ \forall_{\omega \in \Omega} [nX(\omega)] \in \mathbb Z$, so $ \forall_{\omega \in \Omega} X_{(n)}(\omega) \in \mathbb Q$

Answer (score 2):

A random variable $Y$ is by definition a discrete random variable if a countable set $S$ exists with $P(Y\in S)=1$.

Now observe that $X_{(n)}$ only takes values in $\left\{\frac{k}{n}\mid k\in\mathbb Z\right\}$ which is a countable set.